# shrl -0x1if (4(%rsp) - I understand the shifting left but don't currently understand the -0x1if... part of the assembly instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I'm still learning assembly currently. The rest of the code is below which I understand and would rather figure out on my own, but the line involving shifting right (shrl) is what I don't understand. What would 0x1if(4(%rsp) mean? Thanks!

```
 400783:    89 7c 24 ec             mov    %edi,-0x14(%rsp)
 400787:    c7 44 24 fc 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rsp)
 40078e:    00 
 40078f:    eb 14                   jmp    4007a5 <f3+0x22>
 400791:    8b 44 24 ec             mov    -0x14(%rsp),%eax
 400795:    83 e0 01                and    $0x1,%eax
 400798:    85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
 40079a:    74 05                   je     4007a1 <f3+0x1e>
 40079c:    83 44 24 fc 01          addl   $0x1,-0x4(%rsp)
 **4007a1:  d1 6c 24 ec             shrl   -0x1if (4(%rsp)***
 4007a5:    83 7c 24 ec 00          cmpl   $0x0,-0x14(%rsp)
 4007aa:    75 e5                   jne    400791 <f3+0xe>
 4007ac:    8b 44 24 fc             mov    -0x4(%rsp),%eax
 4007b0:    f7 d8                   neg    %eax
 4007b2:    c3                      retq
```

Comment: That looks like a copy-paste error.

Comment: Judging by the unbalanced count of **(** and **)**, it's almost certainly a typo.

Comment: I used objdump to create the text file i got this from, so I'm assuming it was an error through there?

Comment: @CarlosArellano That would be rather unusual.  Perhaps there was some sort of file corruption. Make sure your hard disk is not defective.

Comment: @fuz hmm I'll make sure to check that out, but yes the typo makes the most sense. Thanks!

Comment: `shrl` is shift right? Unless the AT&T is even more cryptic then I thought. (vs title, body it's ok)

Comment: @Ped7g Yes, that's correct. The `l` indicates a “long word” (32 bit) operand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
4007a1:  d1 6c 24 ec             shrl   -0x1if (4(%rsp)
```

There was probably some sort of OCR error happening.  The encoded instruction clearly indicates that this is supposed to be `shrl -0x14(%rsp)`.